# How I can access to menubar and sub ment on another application from my c# application?

Tags: c#, windows, user32, spy++

I'm trying to automate an application. I can send text to a text control and send enter key after wrote my text.
Now I want to access menu bar and sub menu such as select file/open and select file to open.
How I do it?
Notice: I'm using Spy++ to get class name and other properties of controls, but menu bar do not have any class name.

Comment: Solved my problem. I sent Alt + related character to open menu and I'm send specific character to choose sub menu. Thanks a lot to RyanDev for answer this Question in Codeproject. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/872621/How-can-I-access-to-menu-and-sub-menu-on-anther-ap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I sent Alt + related character to open a menu. I'm sending a  specific character to choose the sub menu. Thanks a lot to RyanDev for answering this Question in Codeproject.